# Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured with Spring, MySql and Gradle

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am working with Spring Boot and MySql. When I launch the application, I get the following error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
      classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
      classpath "mysql:mysql-connector-java:$sqlClientVersion"
  }

dependencies {
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.20'
}
```

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: There is cj extra in driver-class-name. And also url has ***** , specify proper url host:port/dbname, why those ****? - make those changes & try once

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html - The name of the class that implements java.sql.Driver in MySQL Connector/J has changed from com.mysql.jdbc.Driver to com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver. The old class name has been deprecated.                                                                                    
 The **** were used to denote the schema name which I didn't wish to expose. Thank you